# Twitter button: wrong count (too many)

Tags: html, gwt, twitter, tweets

I am using this TWEET BUTTON code in my web (inserted from GWT):

```
<a href=\"https://twitter.com/share\" class=\"twitter-share-button\"
data-url=\"http://www.example.com/#!v;id="+diagramId+"\" 
data-text=\""+diagramTitle+"\" data-via=\"example\">Tweet</a>
```

When I click on it, the result is correct. This tweet is posted:

**MYTITLE http://www.example.com/#!v;id=r5sWfujKlSua via @example**

However, what is wrong is the data-count that the button displays. I would say it is counting the total amount of tweet of `http://www.example.com` instead of `http://www.example.com/#!v;id=r5sWfujKlSua` (which should be 0 and its 79).

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URL encode the # symbol with %23.  This is similar to adding hash tags to the tweeted message, as discussed in this [discussion on dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/512); see the reply by Ben Ward.

Only using HTML and javascript (no GWT), the following counts example.com, since the # tag is not encoded in the data-counturl property:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
    data-url="http://www.example.com/#!v;id=0" 
    data-counturl="http://www.example.com/#!v;id=0" data-via="example">Tweet</a>
```

When I replace # with %23 in the data-counturl property, I get a number of 0:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" 
    data-url="http://www.example.com/#!v;id=0" 
    data-counturl="http://www.exmaple.com/%23!v;id=0 data-via="example">Tweet</a>
```

Comment: Very interesting! However URL 'http://www.example.com/%23!v\;id=0' takes you to a different (invalid) site, instead of the correct 'http://www.example.com/#!v\;id=0'. Should I then implement a servlet to transform %23 back #?

Comment: In addition, you added a \ after the !v. For any reason in particular?

Comment: I updated my answer.  You do not need to implement any servlets.  The URL encoding needs to happen in the data-counturl property.  The \ after the !v was also a typo.